# Getting this error: ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 1, column 28: ORA-00936: missing expression</p>

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I tried running this code in ORACLE APEX for a button

```
UPDATE "OALTERR"."APXTER_LOOKUP_VALUES" 
SET "MEANING" = 'Y',
"LOOKUP_CODE" = 'Y' 
where "LOOKUP_TYPE" = 'UPLOADS_FREEZE_ADHOC'
```

This code is running fine in sql developer, I don't know what is the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly "for a button"?

Usually, we create a **process**, put that code in there, and make it run when that specified button is pressed.

I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Yes, I created a dynamic action by right clicking on the button and added a pl/sql code inside it, this worked for me.

Comment: That would be another option, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic action (by right clicking) and add a pl/sql or any other action you want to perform on the click of a button under True condition. This worked for me.